# change value of dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

i want to assign value to 0 if its 1 and vice versa on clicking the button then save it to an array there may be 20-25 buttons based on the query

```
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    <button  class="btn-success btn-sq btn-lg " value="0" id="<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" onclick="toggle(this) ">
        <?php echo $row[0]; ?> <br>
    </button>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: And where are these 1's and 0's coming from? $row[0]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx for the help this worked for me

```
<script>
    function toggle(a)
{
    if(a.value==1)
    {
        a.value=0;   
    }
    else
    {
        a.value=1;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply looking to toggle the value, here's a simple jsfiddle which can do just that: https://jsfiddle.net/fz1o0dsr/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('value', $this.attr('value') === "0" ? "1" : "0");
    alert("The button val is now " + $this.attr('value'));
  });
});
```

Comment: thanx got a simple solution